# represent list of numbers with one value

Tags: data-analysis, discrete-geometry

I have database which each row contains list of numbers, The list of numbers represent a line (The numbers are the change from the last number and not absolute)

I would like to find a way to represent each row with one value, so When I'll have another list of numbers(means new line but not from the DB) I'll be able to order all the rows(which represent lines) from the most similar to the most different in fast way.

- Comparing each row to the list which I have is not an option because I need it to be super fast.

One way I thought of was to calculate the line as a vector length and take all the closest matches of the length from the total list and so to reduce the total list lines to compare, but then I'll still will have to compare each matching length line to the original one, because even if it's the same length it can contains the numbers that assemble the line in different order...

Example of line:

> 0.56,0.74,1.76,1.49,1.15,0.96,0.95,0.56,0.54,-0.61,-0.33,-0.32,-1.82,-1.72,-2.52,-1.73,-0.56,-0.74,-1.71,0.43,-1.00,-2.77,-2.70,-3.05,-2.98,-2.86,-3.56,-2.58,-0.46,-2.05,-0.53

Comment: You haven't told us how you are measuring the similarity of two rows. Without that, I don't think it's possible to give an answer.

Comment: So, please clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - the row represents line, the line is assembled from 31 values that each value is percents that present the change from the last point. I added an example of line values in the post.
The line will be best match if the values are similar to each other so it will be drawn the same (Not exactly the same but where the line is going up it will go up in both of them and so on...)

Comment: 1. Your explanation of how to measure the similarity of two rows should be in the body of the question, not in the comments. 2. You still haven't given enough detail for anyone to be able to tell which of two given sequences is the more similar to a third given sequence. 3. What you're asking for most likely doesn't exist, even if each row is assembled from only two values, let alone 31 values. For each row then corresponds to a point in the plane, and you are looking for a way to order points scattered around the plane so points are close in your order if and only if close in the plane.

Comment: Forget my way, It's not really important if I could measure similarity in fastest way,

Comment: So, any thoughts about the answer I posted?

Comment: Didn't check it yet, but thanks for the answer. I roughly heard about the "nearest neighbor search" algorithm, Is the DB suppose to be ordered first by any fields? I'll check your answer deeply on Tuesday and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is called "nearest neighbor search", and the short answer is, it's a hard problem. I suggest you read up on it – this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) entry is a good starting point – and then report back to us on what you have found. You could also have a look at this discussion on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901139/closest-point-to-a-given-point) and the "linked" and "related" questions there, and this discussion at [MathWorks](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/107029-find-closest-coordinates-to-a-point), and this one at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points), and probably a lot of others that you can find by typing relevant phrases into the internet.